# How do I get Skydrive working?

Tags: wine, sync, cloud, storage

Does anyone know how to make [Skydrive](https://skydrive.live.com/) desktop tool work with 12.04?

Comment: WineHQ still has this listed as status, "Garbage".
I haven't been able to install it via Crossover and it does through Wine program loader (a problem with KERNEL32.dll)
No further luck with PlayOnLinux either, so if anyone manages to get it going, well done and please share your method! :) All the best, Neil.

Comment: I have already tested it in Wine but with no success
For chrome there is an extension... I have it and works fine. the unique "problem" is that you have to create /edit the docs online...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to run it in WINE. Use WineTricks to download all the dlls and stuff you will need to get it working in WINE.